# Undefined when returning $http promise in controller from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

No matter what I do I always get `$$state` or `undefined` back from my factory API call. I've tried promises and simply returning `response.data` from `.then` but nothing I tried works.

I can get the proper response data into my controller but then when I try to assign it to anything I just get `undefined` or `$$state`, depending on which method I use.

My factory:

```
factory('forecastFactory', function ($http, $q, SundialConfig) {
    var Forecast = {}; 
    var weatherKey = SundialConfig.openWeatherKey;

    Forecast.dayCnt = 1; 
    Forecast.prepareCity = function (city) {
        city === undefined ? city = 'Chicago, IL' : city = city;
        return city; 
    }

    Forecast.getForecast = function (city) {
        var preparedCity = Forecast.prepareCity(city);
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?', {
            params: {
                appid: weatherKey,
                q: preparedCity,
                cnt: Forecast.dayCnt,   
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log("success");
            deferred.resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error');
        });

        return deferred.promise; 
    }

    return Forecast;
});
```

My controller:

```
controller('ForecastController', function ($scope, $location, forecastFactory, locationService) { 
    vm = this; 
    forecastFactory.getForecast('Chicago, IL').then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        vm.forecast = res; 
    });
});
```

Comment: try changing to `deferred.resolve(res.data)`. First `res` is  promise object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `$q` because $http returns a promise,

you can do

```
Forecast.getForecast = function(city) {
        var preparedCity = Forecast.prepareCity(city);
        return $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?', {
            params: {
                appid: weatherKey,
                q: preparedCity,
                cnt: Forecast.dayCnt,   
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        })
        .then(function(res) {
      console.log("success");
      return res.data;

    })

    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('error')
      return []; // or {} depending upon required data
    });
    }
```

and in controller, do the same as you are doing now

Other way is simply return the promise returned by $http

```
Forecast.getForecast = function(city) {
        var preparedCity = Forecast.prepareCity(city);

        return $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?', {
            params: {
                appid: weatherKey,
                q: preparedCity,
                cnt: Forecast.dayCnt,   
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        }) 
    }
```

and in controller do this

```
Sundial.Controllers.

controller('ForecastController', ['$scope', '$location', 'forecastFactory', 'locationService', function($scope, $location, forecastFactory, locationService) { 

    vm = this; 

    forecastFactory.getForecast('Chicago, IL').then(function(res) {
        console.log(res)
        vm.forecast = res.data; 
    }, function(err){
          // do something
     })

}]);
```

Comment: First one returns nothing

Comment: what about second one

Comment: close but first `then` of `$http` returns a promise object and `data` is property of that object

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add `return` before $http.jsonp in first case

Comment: Neither of these worked. I still get the object when inside the .then block but vm.forecast still comes up as undefined in the end

Comment: as @charlietfl said, I missed `res.data` , kindly have a look at the updated answer